# No element after component is rendering on the screen React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a react native project I am building. On the home screen I want to render a list of components called PropertyTile with some text in between just for testing. With my current code, it is rendering the first instance of the PropertyTile, but not rendering anything after that. It is extremely wierd and I can not find a solution to this issue for some reason. Why would it only show the first PropertyTile without rendering anything else.

Code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import PropertyTile from '../components/PropertyTile.js'

const HomeScreen = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.screenContainer}>
      <PropertyTile/>
      <Text>Home Screen: Shows currentl asdfasdf!</Text>
      <Text>Home Screen: Shows currentl fe!</Text>
      <PropertyTile />
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  header: {
    fontSize: 22
  },
  screenContainer: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column'
  }
})

export default HomeScreen
```

[current screen rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKBy2.png)

PropertyTile Code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native'
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Image } from 'react-native'

export default function PropertyTile() {

  let deviceWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width - 16
  var aspectHeight = (deviceWidth / 1.78) + 1

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={[styles.imageContainer,{height: aspectHeight}]}>
        <Image style={styles.mainImage} source={require('../../assets/luxury-home-1.jpeg')}/>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.contentContainer}>
        <View style={styles.priceContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.price}>$ 1,259,999</Text>
          <Text style={styles.status}>For Sale</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.addressContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.address}>23 Lowlette Lane.</Text>
          <Text style={styles.address}>Mission Viejo, CA 92692</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.separator}></View>
        <View style={styles.details}>
          <Text style={styles.summary}>6 Beds | 6 Baths | 10,000 Sqft. | 1.3 acre Lot</Text>
          <Text style={styles.homeType}>Single Family Residence</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.separator}></View>
        <View style={styles.details}>
          <View style={styles.metricContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.metricName}>Net Operating Income (Monthly): </Text>
            <Text style={styles.metricValue}>$5,789</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.metricContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.metricName}>Cash on Cash Return: </Text>
            <Text style={styles.metricValue}>2.45%</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.metricContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.metricName}>Return on Initial Investment: </Text>
            <Text style={styles.metricValue}>9.97%</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.disclaimerContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.disclaimer}>*** 30 year fixed, 20% down, 3.14% interest rate | $3,443 rent ***</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    height: '100%',
    paddingTop: 8,
    paddingHorizontal: 8,
    borderRadius: 6,
    overflow: 'hidden'
  },
  imageContainer: {
    width: '100%',
    borderTopLeftRadius: 6,
    borderTopRightRadius: 6,
    overflow: 'hidden'
  },
  mainImage: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%'
  },
  contentContainer: {
    width: '100%',
    backgroundColor: '#D3D3D3',
    borderBottomLeftRadius: 6,
    borderBottomRightRadius: 6,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    paddingHorizontal: 8
  },
  priceContainer: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    paddingTop: 8,
  },
  price: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 24
  },   
  addressContainer: {
    display: 'flex',
    marginTop: 8
  },
  address: {
    fontSize: 14
  },
  separator: {
    marginHorizontal: '3%',
    marginVertical: 8,
    height: 2,
    width: '94%',
    backgroundColor: 'grey'
  },  
  homeType: {
    marginTop: 4,
  },
  metricContainer: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    marginTop: 4
  },
  metricValue: {
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  },
  disclaimerContainer: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    marginVertical: 8,
    width: '100%',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },  
  disclaimer: {
    fontSize: 12,
  }
})
```

Comment: It'd be better if you can add PropertyTile component code.

Comment: I will add it as an update to the original question. @omer.ersoy

Comment: I want to refactor some of the code but I want to be able to see miltiple PropertyTile before i refactor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your `aspectHeight` variable in your **PropertyTile** component is preventing the second instance from appearing. `aspectHeight` is applying a height that spans the height of the screen, pushing the other instances out of view.

You can try wrapping your HomeScreen in a ScrollView so you can see all of the elements that render below the screen's window, like this:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, ScrollView } from 'react-native'
import PropertyTile from '../components/PropertyTile.js'

const HomeScreen = () => {
  return (
    <ScrollView>
    <View style={styles.screenContainer}>
      <PropertyTile/>
      <Text>Home Screen: Shows currentl asdfasdf!</Text>
      <Text>Home Screen: Shows currentl fe!</Text>
      <PropertyTile />
    </View>
    </ScrollView>
  )
}
```

Comment: No i am getting the same issue. Aspect height's value is 232 so it is not the entire screen... the scroll view did not do anything

Comment: I got rid of the image section completely and i am still getting the same issue

Comment: I now what happened. The style for the PropertyTile component height was set to 100% so it was taking up the whole screen. I got rid of it and it worked.